# JavaScript function not working

Tags: java, javascript

using string buffer in java i append javascript for example

```
StringBuffer sb1=new StringBuffer();

sb1.append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n function callauto(){ ");
sb1.append(" var get_deci"+i+"=eval("+c_c+ "&&"+splitvalue_text[0]+"=="+d_d+"?true:false);");
sb1.append("if(get_deci"+i+"){ alert(\"ok\");}");
sb1.append("}</script><script>callauto();</script>");
```

using ajax i get the stringbuffer and display the stringbuffer using servlet printwriter in browser
but above js  function callauto not works value `c_c,splitvalue_text[0],d_d` are generated dynamically.
if  above condition satisfies it returns  true then it shows alert.

Comment: You say it's not working - what exactly isn't working & what is the error? We need much more information!

Comment: Is splitvalue_text array a string array? If so, you need single quotes around splitvalue_text[0] and other string values (maybe c_c and d_d)

Comment: On a side note, you will pull out fewer hairs if you use a template engine like Freemarker to generate your dynamic content. Makes debugging problems CONSIDERABLY easier. Great for maintainability as well. http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because the call doesn't have `type="text/javascript"`

```
<script type="text/javascript">callauto();</script>
```

Also, you don't need to evaluate and then assign it to a variable before being passed to the if condition. You can directly use the value in the if condition as so:

```
"if(" +c_c+ "&&" + splitvalue_text[0]+ "==" +d_d+ ") {"
```

Comment: Specifying script type is not necessary, a plain script tag is enough. See http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is actually

```
c_c && splitvalue_text[0] == d_d
```

which is equal to

```
c_c && (splitvalue_text[0] == d_d)

->  eval(true && false == false) -> true
```

double check if that really is the expression you had in mind.